# Black screen while connecting Windows server 2012 through Remmina

Tags: remmina

I am getting black screen when I try to connect Windows Server 2012 from remmina, While this  remmina can connect windows server 2008 R2 and other Ubuntu servers. 
I have also cross checked that Windows server 2012 can be opened by another windows 7 host through Remote desktop.

[image]

Comment: For me the solution was to change the resolution from a specified value to "client resolution". It instantly worked after that. I was able to immediately close the connection, and change back to using a resolution that I picked (1280x960).

Answer (score 5):

Open the session's configuration windows. Choose the **Basic** tab. Change the color depth. You're probably using one that's not supported by the machine you are connecting to. Check the attached picture. (Sorry for the badly edited screenshot. I'm not very good with Gimp. But I tried focusing on the option I'm talking about, so I blurred everything else. It's actually the first time I do this ever and I consider it an accomplishment, it took time to figure out how to do it :D)

[image]

Comment: This helps. I've also found that on Ubuntu 14.04 you may have to change the resolution from "Use Client Resolution" to something smaller. That worked for me for opening Azure VMs